# The Oxford Comma and its relation to a list with only two entries.

Tags: lists, oxford-comma

The sentence is as follows:
I work in disaster management and prevention, and international aid and development.

2 Questions:
Can a list include just two entries as above?
Can the Oxford comma be used in a two entry list as above?

Google is struggling to answer this but I believe the above is correct.

Comment: I personally avoid the Oxford Comma and would rewrite the above as "I work in disaster management & prevention as well as international aid & development." You can always rephrase a sentence to make clear what you are trying to say.  See this [Grammarly blog entry](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/).

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that Google is struggling to answer this. The very first line in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) specifically says “a series of three or more”. So no, the Oxford or serial comma cannot be used in a ‘list’ of two things like this. As Yosef says, though, a normal, disambiguating comma can. Personally, I’d rephrase: “I work in disaster management and prevention, as well as in international aid and development”.

Comment: Wikipedia is not known for being 100% accurate. Oxfords site does not specify the number of entries in the list.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 You are right, splitting the sentence like that is preferable. I was trying to shorten the sentence but it may be for the best. I am restricted to a very small word count but needs must.

Comment: "and" -->"&" saves you four letters.

Comment: I can't use symbols in this text unfortunately, it's very formal and the symbol will look unprofessional.

Comment: Alternately: *I work in disaster management and prevention, and **in** international aid and development.*

Comment: @Yosef Baskin You might like to correct your comment to: '... you are breaking up a potential confusion between noun groups that have internal **_and_**'s. Therefore, even if your style sheet did not standardize to 'comma and,' your comma helps your sentence because it helps the reader. I vote for the reader over the style sheet.' // What the "comma used before an 'and' before the final member of a (two-, three- ...) member list" is called (ie whether a different term than 'Oxford comma' is needed when there are only two members) is largely irrelevant.

Comment: You are not using an Oxford comma, you are breaking up a potential confusion between noun groups that have internal and's. Therefore, even if your style sheet did not standardize to 'comma and,' your comma helps your sentence because it helps the reader. I vote for the reader over the style sheet.